# Do you need to use mysqli_real_escape_string for encrypted values?

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

I'm working on a project called ThePeopleHubProject, and on the registration you need to input a password.

Do I need to secure the passwords from `SQL injection` if they are encrypted?

I use `crypt(sha1())` as a encryption method.

Thanks,
Thomas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need to**, you can either restrict your `input field of password` to allow/accept what combination it needs.

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['password'])
     $password = htmlentities($_POST['password']) // This will ensure any html characters entered to their equivalent value.
     md5 or sha1($password);
```

**To basically sum-up my answer**, encrypting is more than enough you don't need to worry about sql-injection here.

Comment: Okay, so I'm safe entering into the database as it is?

Comment: @user2999920: yes, you are safe.. as you are only going to deal with the encrypted value not the actualy string entered.